# EXC_BAD_ACCESS from checking if statement conditions?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error message in my app. Based on a bunch of NSLog's I've been able to determine that this is being caused while checking the conditions of an if statement. My if statement is the following:

```
if ( ([todaysDate compare:mostRecentDate] != NSOrderedSame) || (mostRecentDate == nil) ) {
   //Do Stuff
}
```

Can someone tell me why I might be getting this error?

NOTE: todaysDate and mostRecentDate are ivar's that get set a different points in the code

Comment: Not enough retain on of these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is more likely to be caused by insufficient retains on your variables. This is especially common when you use an autoreleased object earlier without retaining the value so you don't own the object, it's deallocated earlier in the run loop.

**EDIT:**
Since you are using an ivar, you could use `@property (retain)` to make sure your ivar is properly retained when you set it or use the `retain` keyword and handle the retain counts yourself.

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS is caused when you send a message to an object that has been deallocated.  Most likely at some point earlier in your code you release todaysDate or mostRecentDate without setting them to nil and thus are sending a message to a released object.

Answer (score 0):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is an operating-system-level exception saying that you're trying to access memory that doesn't belong to your application. This typically happens when an object has its ownership relinquished prematurely (sending `release` to early), or when you have not explicitly taken ownership of an object that you should have (using `retain`). There are a few things you can do in this situation:

1. Run the [static analyser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/), this will help catch cases where you have neglected the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).
2. [Enable zombies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH7-SW3). This will tell you if you are trying to send an instance to a deallocated object.